# Java - driver.findElement #2

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have this button:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="alert alert-danger">
<strong>Pozor!</strong> Je třeba aktualizovat formulář kvůli změnám hodnot v personálním formuláři.  <a href="#" id="newVehicles_reCompPersonnelInput" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger pull-right reCompPersonnelInput">Přepočítat</a>       
</div>
</div>
```

There is no problem to find it with `WebElement prepocitat = driver.findElement(By.id("newVehicles_reCompPersonnelInput"));`

But the button is present in certain situations only. How can I avoid NoSuchElementException?

Comment: Please clarify your Questions.

Are you dealing with an alert that pops up based on certain behaviour ?
Or Is element visible in some runs and not consistently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `findElements`, if the element doesn't exists it will simply return an empty list ans save the need for expensive `try - catch`

```
List<WebElement> prepocitat = driver.findElements(By.id("newVehicles_reCompPersonnelInput"));
if (prepocitat.size > 0) {
    prepocitat.get(0).click();
}
```

Comment: This is what the [Selenium docs](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-) state is a best practice. `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead.`

Answer (score -2):

```
try
{
    WebElement prepocitat = 
    driver.findElement(By.id("newVehicles_reCompPersonnelInput"));
}
catch(NoSuchElementException)
{
    do your action here
}
```

Comment: thanks, almost perfect :-) try
  {
   WebElement prepocitat = driver.findElement(By.id("newVehicles_reCompPersonnelInput"));prepocitat.click();Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
  catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e)
  {
  }

Comment: Ok great! :) Would appreciate it if you would mark this answer as the answer to your question :)

Comment: See Guy's answer for the best practice here.

Answer (score -2):

You can do a fluentWait

```
 static Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(elementWaitTime, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(2,SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

 public WebElement getAnyElement(By byLocator){

  return wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator));       

  }
```

Use Method Like or Anyway you want

```
getAnyElement(By.id("someID")).click();
```

Comment: He says: But the button is present in certain situations only. How can I avoid NoSuchElementException?

Comment: As understood and also seen on markup : "But the button is present in certain situations only. How can I avoid NoSuchElementException?"
Meant that he was looking on a way to click the element since sometimes it works and sometimes an exception is thrown.

Answer (score -2):

working solution from Anand's advice:

```
try 
{ 
WebElement prepocitat = driver.findElement(By.id("newVehicles_reCompPersonnelInput")‌​);
prepocitat.click()‌​;Thread.sleep(1000); 
} 
catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) { }
```

Comment: Thread.sleep is not a good practice consider using implicit or explicit waits